# Visual Studio Online, multiple Cloud projects, Continuous Integration

Tags: azure, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution with 3 cloud service projects (1 Web Role, 2 Worker Roles) and a set of nUnit tests hosted in Visual Studio Online.

Through Azure portal, I've setup a continuous integration build that builds and deploys my solution on checkin.  Azure, however asked me for a single Cloud Service to deploy solution into (although my project contains 3 of them) and obviously, the build only deploys one of the cloud projects (presumably the first one it finds).  How can I make it deploy all three?

I'd rather not create three different builds.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this besides splitting up the cloud services into their own solutions?  I have multiple builds, but all my cloud service in the same solution and it always tries to deploy the first cloud service it finds.

Comment: Nope, building all individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, you cannot deploy all of your azure projects within your solution to azure  at the same time using the VSO CI builds.  If you look at your CI build definition under process you'll see that you can only specify one cloud service name to deploy to.  We ended up having to create one solution, with one azure project, and one CI build per cloud service.  We use the staging environments as a temporary deployment destination until all of our services are built/deployed, then swap them all at the same time to achieve a somewhat seamless/instant update.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the new VSO VBuild Next System in TFS 2015.

You are able to build a specific *.ccproj cloud service project and from there use a specific task to publish to azure.

This allows me to have multiple cloud services and multiple web roles in the same solution.

You should also be able to build multiple cloud service projects and setup multiple publish tasks, all from the same build definition.

From MS...

> We've built a brand new scriptable build system that's web-based and
>   cross-platform. We believe all new and most existing customers should
>   use it instead of the XAML build system.

More info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/overview

Here is a view of my build tasks..

[image]